# Javascript framework canJs control.route

Tags: javascript, canjs, canjs-routing

I would like use [this tuto](http://bitovi.com/blog/2012/05/hashchange-routing-can-route-1.html), but doesn't work for me

```
    $(function() {

    Router = can.Control({

      "completed route" : function(){
        console.log("the hash is #!completed")
      },
      "active route" : function(){
        console.log("the hash is #!active")
      },
      "project/create" : function(){
        console.log("the hash is #!project/create")
      },
      "route" : function(){
        console.log("empty hash")
      }
    });

    // make sure to initialize the Control
    new Router(document);

    });
```

I use `window.location.hash = "!#completed"` or `<a href="#!active">Show Active</a>`
no message is displayed in console.

I use canjs 2.0.4 with JQuery

Thank for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call [can.route.ready()](http://canjs.com/docs/can.route.ready.html) to initialize the routing:

```
Router = can.Control({
  "completed route" : function(){
    console.log("the hash is #!completed")
  },
  "active route" : function(){
    console.log("the hash is #!active")
  },
  "route" : function(){
    console.log("empty hash")
  }
});

// make sure to initialize the Control
new Router(document);

can.route.ready();
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DeGR5/